# How can I update/add a custom metadata on GCS using React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I want to update the custom metadata set in the GCS bucket from Jane Doe to John Doe as metadata.name. Tried some codes but it wont reflect and update the bucket metadata.

Is there a way to replace Code 1 and 2 to a fetch method? These Codes work in groovy whenever I put this in shellscript but not in Reactjs. Is there a way to use this in FETCH METHOD?

Code 1

```
curl -X PATCH --data-binary '{
  "metadata": {
    "name": 'John Doe'
  }
}' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o/OBJECT_NAME"
```

Code 2

```
gsutil setmeta -h "name:'John Doe'" gs://BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME
```

Already tried these 2codes but this wont work

```
updateMetadata = (newName) => {
 const { token } = this.props;
 return fetch('https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o/OBJECT_NAME', {
  'method': 'PATCH',
  'headers': new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': token
  }),
  'data': Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({
    'metadata': { 'name': newName }
   }))
 })
 .then( response => {return response.json()})
 .then( res => { return res })
}
```

```
updateMetadata = (newName) => {
 const { token } = this.props;
 const data = new FormData()
 data.append('name', newName)
 return fetch('https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o/OBJECT_NAME', {
  'method': 'PATCH',
  'headers': new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': token
  }),
  'body': data
 })
 .then( response => {return response.json()})
 .then( res => { return res })
}
```

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: The metadata in the gcs bucket is not updating at all. It remains the same

Comment: And you haven't error message/code? That's strange!!